# Accessing azure database in Windows Phone 8.1 app to find shortest distance of a place around

Tags: c#, azure, windows-phone-8.1

I have a database in azure which consists of lattitude and longitude, and I am trying to get those values and find the values with the shortest distance from the current place. (in the future I intend to plot the place corresponding to the shortest distance on a map) but I am not being able to do so.
The Read() function on MainPage.xaml.cs looks as below:

```
private async void Read()

    {
        {   Geolocator geo = new Geolocator();
            Geoposition pos = await geo.GetGeopositionAsync();

             await App.MobileService.GetTable<Sighting>().ReadAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
                {

                    System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Sighting> items = t.Result;
                    List<double> distances=new List<double>();
                      foreach (var record in items)
                      {


                          lati = record.Lattitude;
                          longi = record.Longitude;

                         double lat2 = lati;
                         double long2 = longi;

          double lat1= pos.Coordinate.Point.Position.Latitude;
          double long1=pos.Coordinate.Point.Position.Longitude;
               double R = 6371;
                          double dLat = (lat2 - lat1)*Math.PI/180;
                          double dLon = (long2 - long1)*Math.PI/180;
                          lat1 = (lat1) * Math.PI / 180;
                          lat2 = (lat2) * Math.PI / 180;
                          double a = Math.Sin(dLat / 2) * Math.Sin(dLat / 2) + Math.Sin(dLon / 2) * Math.Sin(dLon / 2) * Math.Cos(lat1) * Math.Cos(lat2);
                          double c = 2 * Math.Atan2(Math.Sqrt(a), Math.Sqrt(1 - a));
                          double d = R * c;
                         distances.Add(d); }
                      distances.Sort();
                      double dd = distances.ElementAt(0);
               });
}
```

Comment: Why the continuewith if you await?

Comment: You should most likely read a good book or tutorial on the C# programming language. It will make your life tremendously easier in the long run. I personally recommend [Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)'s [C# in depth](http://www.manning.com/skeet3/?a_aid=jonskeet&a_bid=66d590c3). This sort of knowledge gap is not something you want to have when coding in the long run.